# How can I enable Typescript 3 unknown type highlighting in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: typescript, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-mac

I'm using **Visual Studio for Mac** (Community 8.2) on **MacOS 10.13.6** for syntax and error highlighting in Typescript.

**Typescript 3.5.3** was installed globally with npm, and therefore supports the `unknown` type, however Visual Studio highlights an error:
`Error: (TS) Cannot find name 'unknown'.`

The code is very basic and should not produce the error, but I'll include it here for completeness:
`let myVariable: unknown = 10;`

Typescript is able to compile the file without modification, so this is not an error with the code, ad would appear to affect the IDE. Does anyone have any insight into how I can enable the correct error output?

As a workaround I can suppress the error by importing unknown-ts, which makes me wonder if somehow VS is using Typescript 2 under the hood.

Comment: Have you tried to update Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild in the Nuget?

Comment: I have no idea where to even start. Does NuGet come with VS on Mac? Any commands? Googling resulted in many Windows-only suggestions.

Comment: Here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/nuget-walkthrough?view=vsmac-2019